# Firebase Cloud function to get near by places?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I have a database in the Firebase real time. Lets call that database as "A". Database "A" contains 1000 rows with each row include latitude and longitude.

I have one more table for Users which contains current location of user.

Now i want to write cloud function which will compare users location with each row of Database "A" and if the distance is less that 50 km then send push notification.

Geofire is good choice but how to create object of Geofire from Database "A". Database "A" get updated every 30 minutes

Database "A" synced with Google sheet which is working fine but I want to send push notification to users only if distance is less that 50 kms.

Comment: did you get solution? I m facing same issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever got this to work? I'm currently looking into something like this with a react-native pp.